# Volume range slider(done)

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling

Task: create volume range slider, when you click on the scale, it should be painted over to the level at which the user clicked the mouse.

I can't use input type range for this task.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="volume-level-block">
        <div class="flex">
          <div class="button">-</div>
          <div class="volume-bar"></div>
          <div class="button">+</div>
        </div>
        <div class="value">100%</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

JS

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
const percent = document.querySelector(".value");
const volumeBar = document.querySelector(".volume-bar");

buttons.forEach((a_button) => {
  a_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    one_step_change(a_button.innerHTML);
  });
});

function one_step_change(sign) {
  perc_value = Number(
    percent.innerHTML.substring(0, percent.innerHTML.length - 1)
  );
  if (sign == "+" && perc_value < 100) {
    percent.innerHTML = perc_value + 1 + "%";
  } else if (perc_value > 0) {
    percent.innerHTML = perc_value - 1 + "%";
  }
}


volumeBar.addEventListener("click", volumeBarHandler);

function volumeBarHandler(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

What I need  to use for this task?

Comment: so you need help with the volume bar?

Comment: yes, I can't understand what I need use for this

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding one example which I created to demonstrate how you can do this.
Right now I have used hard coded values, you can modify it according to your needs. My main goad is just to given you one example so that you can try it out.

**My Idea here is:**

We should have one `div #slider`, and it contains two more divs one to show some colour `div #vol_level` to show this is level of volume, and one to show empty area left `div #empty`.
And when user clicks on `div #slider`, we find the location of click and change the width of `div #vol_level` and `div #empty` accordingly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
    #slider {
        height: 20px;
        width: 300px;
        display:inline-block;
        float: left;
    }
    
    #vol_level {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        background: green;
        float: left;
    }
    
    #empty {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: lightgray;
        float: left;
    }
    
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Volume Slider</h1>
    <p>Current volume Level: <span id="vol_text">0%</span> </p>
    <div id="slider">
      <div id="vol_level"></div>
      <div id="empty"></div>
    </div>
<div>

<script>
    var volumeLevel = document.getElementById("vol_level")
    var empty = document.getElementById("empty")
    var slider = document.getElementById("slider")
    var text = document.getElementById("vol_text")

    slider.addEventListener("click", volumeChange);

    function volumeChange(e) {
        var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        var x = e.clientX - slider.style.left; 
    
        volumeLevel.setAttribute("style",`width:${x}px`);
        empty.setAttribute("style",`width:${300 - x}px`);
    
        var calc = (1.0 * x) / (300.0) * 100;
    
        text.innerHTML = `${Math.trunc(calc)}%`;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.
You can comment if you face any problem or have some doubts.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is how the code should be done. There is room for improvement like listening for minus or plus button hold or clicking and scrolling the volume bar, but I leave that for you. The current code should get you in the right direction :)

```js
let percentValue = 100;

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
const percent = document.querySelector(".value");
const volumeBar = document.querySelector(".volume-bar");

buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", buttonClick);
});

function buttonClick(event) {
    let sign = event.currentTarget.innerHTML;
    if (sign == "+")
        percentValue++;
    else if(sign == "-")
        percentValue--;
    
    if(percentValue < 0)
        percentValue = 0;

    if(percentValue > 100)
        percentValue = 100;

    updatePercent();
}


volumeBar.addEventListener("click", volumeBarHandler);

function volumeBarHandler(event) {
    let rect = event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    let x = event.clientX - rect.left; // x position within the element

    percentValue = Math.round((x / rect.width) * 100);

    updatePercent();
}

function updatePercent(){
    let currentPercentString = percentValue + "%";
    percent.innerHTML = currentPercentString;
    volumeBar.style.background = `linear-gradient(90deg, red 0%, red ${currentPercentString}, gray ${currentPercentString},gray 100%)`;
}
```

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    gap: 5px;
}

.volume-level-block {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
}

.button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.volume-bar{
    width: 170px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="volume-level-block">
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="button">-</div>
            <div class="volume-bar"></div>
            <div class="button">+</div>
        </div>
        <div class="value">100%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my idea for your slider. to adjust the slider, set value to custom css property `--volume-value` by using `volumeBar.style.setProperty("--volume-value", "/* value in percentage */")`.

```css
.volume-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.volume-track {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: var(--volume-value, 0);
  background-color: gray;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.volume-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: var(--volume-value, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 8px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<div style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div class="volume-bar" style="--volume-value: 50%">
    <div class="volume-track"></div>
    <span class="volume-handle"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is wrong because a value is hardcoded, another man give the best answer, thanks.

Comment: i've described how you can change the value at the top. i thought you could code it yourself.